# Getting last modified date or flag from a public image on Amazon S3

Tags: ios, amazon-s3

I have a bucket on amazon s3 that has an image, this image is public so it has the following pattern:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/AdBannerOnline.png (this file doesn't exist)

What I would like to do is, make  my application check if the image on the address is newer to a locally stored one, if it is newer the app would download it, but if it is not, then it wouldn't.

My question is, how can I check the date or another flag and download to know if i should download the image?

(Without actually having to download the file?)

Edit: I am NOT using the aws sdk or anything, you can think of this as an image hosted anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a `HEAD` request on the S3 URL rather than a `GET` request, S3 will return all of the headers it would normally return if you downloaded the file but will not send the body of the object.  So, you could check the headers for things like `Last-Modified` to determine whether to actually download the object or not.  See [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html) for details.